# Highchart treegraph marker padding and spacing

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I am using treegraph type because it fits best for the project I am working on. However, since I have a lot of data, many of the markers overlaps on the graphs. I am wondering if there is anyway to create some padding around each marker. Highchart GPT recommonded me to use nodePadding, but it didn't work and I don't find it under highchart reference with for tree map. Here is what the chart currently looks like. I want to create paddings around each marker that the red markers don't overlap. Is there a defaullt value to for paddings of each node. I have tried nodePadding already but it is not creating any spaces between the markers. I have also tried to use set a fixed body height and width to a really high pixle value but it only reduces the problem minimally.

```
Here's an inline link to y jsfiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/thomasxiao/jx2qk731/80/ ).
```

Comment: What about changing the marker radius? Check the base demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6zgjfv4L/ and compare with reduced marker radius for the 6 level : https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5k2Lqnec/